# MySQL request in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

In my code I have three requests to a MySQL database:

```
@app.route('/private', methods=['POST'])
def private():
    login = request.form['login']
    if login is None or not login:
        return jsonify(data='Incorrect URL')

    try:
        c, conn = cursor_connection()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT accounts_info_uid "
                  "FROM auth_info WHERE login='{}' ".format(login))

        id = c.fetchall()
        if not id:
            return jsonify(data='Incorrect login')

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM boxes_id AS tb1 LEFT JOIN"
                  " accounts_info AS tb2 ON tb2.boxes_ids=tb1.uid "
                  # "LEFT JOIN electricity_info as tb3 ON tb3.boxes_id_uid=tb1.uid"
                  " WHERE tb2.uid={} ".format(id[0][0]))

        uid, mc_address, working_status, activation_status, _,\
        first_name, second_name, registration_date, phone, email, boxes_id = c.fetchall()[0]
        c.execute(" SELECT consumed_electricity "
                  "FROM electricity_info "
                  "WHERE boxes_id_uid={} ".format(boxes_id))
        consumed_electricity = [float(val[0]) for val in c.fetchall()]
        c.close()
        conn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(msg='Cannot execute /private {}'.format(e))
        return str(e)
```

I fetched a list from electricity info by primary key in `boxes_id` (so in `electricity_info` it is called `boxes_id_uid`).

Structure of pk in my tables:

```
auth_info --------> pk is accounts_info_uid

boxes_id ----------> pk is uid

accounts_info ------> pk is uid and it is connected to table boxes_id by field boxes_id

electricity_info ------> pk is boxes_id_uid
```

I think it can be optimized in one SQL request. If so, can you tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: This is full of SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to fix it and optimize it?

Comment: @John Use a ORM framework like [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee).

Comment: If I change format() to %s will it solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **DONT!** String format your sql queries, but let the cursor do it for you.

   *As [@Gareth Rees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees) said, this is not secure!*

   > ```
   > c.execute("SELECT accounts_info_uid "
   >           "FROM auth_info WHERE login='{}' ".format(login))
   > ```

   As taken from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html), this would be the proper way to execute statements with sql:

   ```
   cursor.execute("SELECT accounts_info_uid FROM auth_info WHERE login = %s", login)
   ```
2. You could use a context manager over the connection

   Using a context manager would improve the readability, [see PEP343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

   [There are some resource out there how to implement such a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067690/context-manager-for-pythons-mysqldb/22840557#22840557)
3. Make the login a separate function
4. I think it can be optimized in one SQL request?

   Yes, but without the database itself it is hard to test, a github repo or some more information would help.

   However you could improve on your google-fu, Simply typing "mysql join 3 tables" would have given you the answer you are looking for.

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql

Comment: Thank you! But I asked to show me the way to combine my three sql-requests into just one.. Is it possible?